# Problem with the fk and pk which are in the same table and related

Tags: mysql, sql

"HProblem with the fk and pk which are in the same table and related."

So, i want to insert in table 'employee' values but the program show me error:

Error Code: 1452. Cannot add or update a child row: a foreign key constraint fails (`ikbo_6`.`employee`, CONSTRAINT `employee_ibfk_1` FOREIGN KEY (`manager_id`) REFERENCES `employee` (`employee_id`)).

```
insert into employee values
(1,'Mccain', 'Jhonny','D',1001,101,'2008-05-12',2000.90,100.45,801);
```

I tried first to add the data to pk_key and only then to the other columns, but this did not work.

```
insert into employee (last_name,first_name,middle_initial,manager_id,job_id,hire_date, salary, commission, department_id) values
('Mccain', 'Jhonny','D',1001,101,'2008-05-12',2000.90,100.45,801);
```

what am I doing wrong?

The struture `employee_id int(6) not null auto_increment primary key,manager_id int(6)`

and `foreign key (manager_id) references Employee (employee_id)`

[relation key](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8BXjS.png)

Comment: Does this answer your question? [MySQL foreign keys on self](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7230145/mysql-foreign-keys-on-self)

Comment: Obviously the row for the manager `1001` doesn't exist.  Add that row first and then the employee.

Comment: I have found a solution. I first added an entry for the PK column separately, and then separately for everyone else, and then I used default